# Internet Access on Player settings is disabled

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can I ask how to enable internet access in player settings in unity ?

My unity version is 2018.2.18f1

[image]

Comment: to me it doesn't seem disabled but "locked" on `Require`

Comment: Same here with Unity 2020. In one project it's locked just like for you, in another project with the same Unity version it's enabled and fine. Haven't seen any other differences in the 2 projects' player settings.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the URL. Unity on android likes to have protocol. For example: www.google.com would need to be put as http://www.google.com.

Comment: hi sir. on my player settings "internet access" is disabled i dont know why?

Comment: can you try disabling firewall or updating network drivers etc

Comment: it was still disable sir. :(

Answer (score 0):

The answer was provided by Krupa Nanda Reddy at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66746987/19521049:

If you turn off Project Settings / Services / Cloud Diagnostics / Crashes and exceptions, then Project Settings / Player / Other Settings / Configuration / Internet Access goes from Required to Auto and becomes editable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).