# Internet Access is always set to required in unity android player settings

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-permissions

I am using unity 2019.4.2f1, I want to remove the internet access permission from the final android manifest file created by unity but, because this option is locked I am not able to remove the permission.
Let me know if there is any-workaround to do so or enable this option somehow.

I saw the there is some performance reporting service is enabled, although I am not using analytics at all only thing I am using is unity collab.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you are using any of the Unity scripting APIs that are intended to be used to access network (even if you are using them for opening local files) Unity will add internet permission. Finally open "WIndow -> Package Manager" and check the packages that are included in your project. Some of the packages (such as ads or analytics) might be included by default, even if you have not included them yourself. Removing such packages would get rid of the permission.

Comment: Leo, I have checked there is no package like analytics. I have Test Framework, TextMeshPro, Unity Collab, Unity UI, visual studio code editor as packages.

Answer (score 0):

In services window, go to cloud diagnostics and disable the crash report. It worked for me and i hope it will work for you too.